# Update product id before windows installation starts based on the selected location

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to create a windows installer that supports installation of multiple instances of the same application which is possible only by having a unique ID for each instance.

Now the question is, I want to have the id set based on the location where it is installed. The ID will be decided based on the location the user selects in the dialog. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question, What are you trying to achieve or what is the requirement behind letting the users to install multiple instances of the same application?

What ID are you talking about ? If you want to achieve this then you will have to change the following MSI properties, Unless you change these property values for each MSI users will not be able to install multiple instances.

1. ProductCode
2. UpgradeCode
3. DetectNewerInstalledVersion property to false

Comment: I have a server running multiple instances of my application. Like two clients using my application. I have services for each application. What I am trying to achieve is to have an installer for services, which will install the services in two different location (one for each server instance). I can differentiate the services by changing the service name. The issue is I wont be updating both the instances of my application at the same time.